# Recall a function without re-initializing every time

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to call a function without re-initializing (hope I used the correct word here) it every time I call it. So the first time it gets called, it should initialize, but after its initialized, it should just use that reference.

Here's the code I'm trying to do it with.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdb42c1z/)

```js
console.clear();

function mainFunction(e) {
  var index = 0;

  function subFunction() {
    console.log(index++);
  }
  return subFunction();
}

window.addEventListener('click', mainFunction)
```

`index` should increase by one every time `mainFunction` gets called. The obvious solution, is to make `index` a global variable (or just out of `mainFunction`). But I need `index to stay in`mainFunction`.

How can I make `index` increment every time (using the same reference) `mainFunction` gets called?

I tried assigning `mainFunction` to a variable, then calling the variable in the event listener,

```
var test = mainFunction;
window.addEventListener('click', test)
```

but that didn't work. The results were the same.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('click', mainFunction());` and `return subFunction;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should correct the code as follows;

```
console.clear();

function mainFunction(e) {
  var index = 0;

  function subFunction() {
    console.log(index++);
  }
  return subFunction; // <<< don't invoke subfunction
}

window.addEventListener('click', mainFunction()) // <<< invoke mainfunction
```

Comment: That calls it right away, and doesn't call it afterwards. I already wrote this comment above. Not sure why still wrote this as an answer???

Comment: Don't you want `subFunction` to be called on each click? If so, this code achieves that

Comment: @fvgs Oh. He's correct! I did `return subFunction()` i.e. with the parenthesis. Thanks!

Comment: How can I make it not call right away, i.e. on page load? It should only get called when the user clicks?

Comment: @Jessica You are adding the event listener when the page loads.. it only logs the next number on the console when the user clicks the mouse button.

Comment: But `mainFunction` gets called right away. if you log something out outside of `subFunction` but in `mainFunction`, it will get called on page load: https://jsfiddle.net/62j1oLpe/

Comment: Also, what is a good tutorial (book, video, or blog) that explains this whole concept (of returning a function and how it gets called etc.)?

Comment: @Jessica I would advise you to read the Chapter 2 of [this book](http://pepa.holla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/The-Principles-of-Object-Oriented-JavaScript.pdf) Well.. this is most probably the "best" book written on fundamentals of JS. You should buy and read all of it..

Comment: One more question... How would I call `mainFunction` regularly (not in an event)? i.e. how would I call `mainFunction` that `mainFunction` would call `subFunction`? I tried `mainFunction()` but it didn't call `subFunction`

Comment: @Jessica In the above code the aim is to keep a variable called `index` in closure. `mainFunction` doesn't invoke `subFunction` but just return a definition of it to the click event listener. Even though `index` is defined in `mainFunction`, `subFunction` has access to the `index` variable (closure) so every time the click event listener invokes `subFunction` it logs the `index` value and increments it. You could have done `var test = mainFunction()` and `test` would become `subFunction` and every time you do `test()`, you get index logged at console and incremented..

Answer (score 0):

maybe try closures?

```
var main = (function () {
var index = 0;
return function () {return index += 1;}
})();

main()
main()
```

//index should be 2...

explain-
The variable main is assigned the return value of a **self-invoking function**.

The self-invoking function only runs once. index initialize only once.

Comment: Why does the self invoking function only runs once?

Comment: here is a good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make `index` global (or one scope higher regarding `mainFunction`), you can use a closure:

```js
var mainFunction = (function () {
    var index = 0;
    return function () {return console.log(index++);}
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="mainFunction()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Why does the self invoking function only runs once?

Answer (score 0):

Using OOP concept is the proper way to achieve this. The following should help you.
If you want to do it in ES6 way follow [this babel example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=class%20MainClass%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(val)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.index%20%3D%20val%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20subFunction()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.index%2B%2B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aconst%20instance%20%3D%20new%20MainClass(0)%0Aconsole.log(instance.subFunction())%0Aconsole.log(instance.subFunction())%0Aconsole.log(instance.subFunction())%0A)

```js
var mainFunction = function(val) {
  this.index = val //initialize this with the fn parameter or set a atatic value
}

mainFunction.prototype.subFunction = function() {
  return this.index++
}

var instance = new mainFunction(0)

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(instance.subFunction())
})
```

```html
<p>Click to see the result </p>
```

Comment: Do you not thing that it's over complicating things by using OOP?

Comment: No, following programming patterns is not a bad thing.

Comment: @Jessica By this was you reuse mainFuntions by creating new instances.

Comment: But I never saw a library that uses a class for a small thing like this.

Comment: @Jessica It's just a good practice. It improves re-usability. If scalabilty is your concern, you should follow this. All the major libraries use OOP concepts to scale.

Comment: Can you show me some that use OOP for a trivial task?

Comment: @Jessica I use ES6 class all the time and it is helpful in scalability. If you don't wanna use, it's your wish.

Comment: I do appreciate that you're trying to help me! I don't mean to be argumentative. I'm just trying to find the correct way to do this. Do you know of any librarys that use this method?

Comment: Lodash, Express, React etc.

Comment: My idea is to write clean code which should solve the problem, should be reusable and scalable.

Comment: @Jessica I never came across that situation. But, I would suggest to have them as two different classes and use them across each other.